# Android how to open last screen on resume

Tags: android, kotlin, android-navigation

This is more of an advice thread so I can't share any code because I have none.

My question is the following:

I have an android app that uses a nav graph and if I leave the app with the system back button it will always open the login screen on resume. So I didn't close the app, I just put it into the background. My start destination is indeed set to this login fragment, but what must I change that the app would open on the screen I close the app on? In this case, it was the screen after login which in my case can point to 2 different fragments, so I can't just hardcode it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it using SharedPreference.

1. In the login fragment make a shared preference and set its value to a boolean.

```
val sharedPreferences:SharedPreferences = this.requireActivity().getSharedPreferences("OnboardingDetails", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

        val boarded: Boolean = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("isLogin", false)

        if (boarded) {
            findNavController().navigate(OnboardingFragmentDirections.actionOnboardingFragmentToTransactionListFragment())
        } else {
            sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("isLogin", true).apply()
        }
```

1. The first time the login screen comes when a user installs the app, the boolean is false.
2. else part of the condition executes making the boolean true. This means the user has already gone through the login screen.
3. When the next time user opens your app, The boolean is true and if part of the condition runs that takes the user to the next fragment automatically.

Answer (score 1):

try to use addToBackStack(null) when add or show the Fragmrnt.

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .addToBackStack(null)//use this to add the fragment to the stack
    .commit;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're backing out of the app with the back button? [As far as the system's concerned](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states#expectations), that's the user closing the app (same as swiping it away) and the expectation is that the app will start "fresh" next time.

> The user's assumption in these complete dismissal cases is that they have permanently navigated away from the activity, and if they re-open the activity they expect the activity to start from a clean state. The underlying system behavior for these dismissal scenarios matches the user expectation - the activity instance will get destroyed and removed from memory, along with any state stored in it and any saved instance state record associated with the activity.

So you're not really putting it into the background, you're destroying the last activity/popping the last item off the backstack, so the app is starting from the beginning of the navigation flow next time you open it. That's standard behaviour.

If you just put it into the background by switching to another app / going to the home screen, it should restore exactly as it when you switch back to it. You can test this by enabling **Don't keep activities** in developer options, so the system will destroy it as soon as it goes into the background.

---

There's an example in the Navigation library docs that pretty much handles this idea - it's basically along the lines of Karmveer's answer, but I thought you might want to see how they recommend doing it:

https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-conditional

But if you do want to set a "default" first page for when the user first opens the app and they're already logged in, you'll have to store that data somewhere so you can check it when deciding where to navigate to. And you'll have to update it as necessary (e.g. whenever the user swaps between them, so you're storing the most recent one). Shared preferences are the usual way, or there's that new `DataStore` thing too if you're into that

Comment: Yes that's what I thought as well. Thanks for the clarification